# intersection of closed sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ a metric space, and $(D_n)_{n\geq 0}\subset X$ bounded closed sets such that $D_{n+1}\subset D_n$. we put $D=\displaystyle\bigcap_{n\geq 0}D_n$. 
Can we proof that $diam(D_n) \longrightarrow diam(D)$ without compactness ?

($diam(K)=\displaystyle\sup_{x,y\in K}d(x,y)$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. A counterexample is $D_n = [n, + \infty) \subset \mathbb{R}$.

A more complicated counterexample follows. I denote by $l^{\infty}$ the Banach space of bounded real valued sequences, with the usual sup norm $||\cdot ||_{\infty}$ .

Let $X = \{ (x_k)_{k \geq 1} \in l^{\infty}: ||(x_k)_{k\geq1}||_{\infty} \leq 1\}$. Clearly $X$ is a bounded metric space, and it is not compact.

Call , for $n\geq 2$,  $D_n = \{ (x_k)_{k \geq 1} \in X : x_1 = \dots = x_n = 0\}$. These $D_n$ form a nested chain of closed subsets of $X$, and their intersection is clearly $\{0\}$. However each of them has diameter equal to $1$.

Comment: yes we can say that but if $diam(D_n)<\infty$

Comment: My idea came up by looking for a bounded metric space, not locally compact. Otherwise I think it's hard to construct a counterexample in a locally compact metric space.

Comment: yes i think so but thank you for that beautiful example

Comment: You can get it for locally compact metric spaces that aren't complete. Let $y$ be a point of the metric space, and $(x_n)$ a Cauchy sequence that doesn't converge. Then set $D_n = \{y\} \cup \{x_k : k > n\}$. The limit of the diameters is $d'(x,y) > 0$ where $x$ is the limit of $(x_n)$ in the completion of your metric space, and $d'$ is the metric on the completion. But the intersection is just $\{y\}$.